# Shortcut created with script not showing up in Start Menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, start-menu, nircmd

I've just started trying to use [`nircmd`](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net). When I made a shortcut in a batch script, the shortcut was successfully created in the folder for my user's Start Menu > All Apps (`%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`), and the Computer's Start Menu folder (`%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`) but for some reason has not shown up in all apps in the start menu.

When I place a shortcut in either location it normally shows up in the All Apps list straight away.

An excerpt from the script I am using to make the shortcut is:

```
set NIR=%cd%\nircmdc.exe
set StartMenuFold=%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
set AllAppsFold=%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
%NIR% shortcut "%PROGRAMFILES%\EsotericIDE\EsotericIDE.exe" "%StartMenuFold%" EsotericIDE
%NIR% shortcut "%PROGRAMFILES%\EsotericIDE\EsotericIDE.exe" "%AllAppsFold%" EsotericIDE
```

What am I doing wrong, or is it simply a problem with `NirCmd`? I could do this manually, but I would like to be able to automate it.

**Edit**: I've tried Using GOW's version of ln to create a link, Windows recognizes it as a shortcut but still does not put it in All Apps Folder

**Edit 2**: It turns out my problem was solely user error on my part... I previously pinned a shortcut to the application the start menu.

Comment: Just to double-check, are you running this command with elevated privileges?  You can't create a shortcut in `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` without admin rights.

Comment: Yeah, I ran the batch file from an admin command prompt.

Comment: I am certainly not a `nircmd` guru, but hopefully someone else will chime in who can help a bit more. If you don't mind me asking, do you have a compelling need to automate this process?

Comment: Don't absolutely need to, but I just wanted to learn how. Now I'm curious as to why these shortcut methods seem to malfunction.

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, running as Administrator

Comment: My problem was probably because of Start Menu shortcut of same name/making a start menu shortcut first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the answer to both parts of my question were here: [Windows 10 start menu missing certain types of shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/1031815/windows-10-start-menu-missing-certain-types-of-shortcuts?rq=1) with the accepted answer.

Basically, I had pinned the application I was targeting with my shortcut's to Windows 10's start menu previously. For some reason, this prevents the same application from being in the Start Menu's all apps list. Both the User Start Menu folder and Windows' start menu folder, in any combination, will make the shortcut appear in the All Apps list otherwise.